# How come the vapour pressure of mercury is so low, when its melting point is also relatively low?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I originally found my way to this by looking into why mercury has such a low melting point for a metal, and the explanation I got was that due to its electron configuration, it acts almost like a "noble metal", leading to a low melting point due to weak bonds. This doesn't seem to work out, however, when considering mercury's extremely low vapour pressure and very high surface tension, which is explained by high intermolecular forces. Evidently I am missing some aspect of the picture, how come these two seemingly contradictory characteristics are found together?

Comment: The vapour pressure of Hg is high, unless you compare it to that of ether or so. Look at the vapour pressure of other metals, instead.

Comment: I hadn't actually considered that, it would make sense for Mercury, but how come metals have such low vapour pressures compared to more common substances? Water has a much higher vapour pressure, but also a higher melting point and lower boiling point. Is it even determined by molecular bond strength as I thought?

Comment: water is a special case. I think you should avoid *high* and *low* in this discussion. At least take the adjective *relative* implicit. Then, I discussion can be done and the situation is variegate.

Comment: Molten metals are still metals, in fact. The force at play is metallic bond, a truly chemical bond (ie relatively strong and dictated by the element electronic structure). Thus relatively high MP and BP. For water, it is special when compared to similar molecules. If you say that it has higher melting point, now you are not comparing it to metals of course. Also look for the bonds that keep solids togheter (ionic, metallic, covalent in covalent solid, other relatively weak forces in molecular solid), it should help at least qualitatively.